# Meteor EC2 Unable to update package catalog

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-ec2, npm

I've been running meteor on my EC2 server instance, until I came across a problem.

The problem started when I removed my project `rm -rf project`, and `scp` the project from my local computer into EC2. I did this because `git clone` was hanging in EC2.

When trying to run meteor by typing in `meteor` in my EC2 instance, the console says only:

```
 Updating package catalog
```

instead of the usual `[[[[[ ~/path/appname ]]]]]`

After hanging for about 30 seconds, console says:

```
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)
```

I'm not offline (I'm sshed into the server) so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Then, I get a message saying

```
This project says that it uses Meteor 1.0.4.2, but you don't have that version of Meteor installed, and we were unable to contact Meteor's update servers to find out about it. Please edit the .meteor/release file in the project and change it to a valid Meteor release, or go online.
```

When I run `meteor update` or `meteor -version` , again console says

```
Updating package catalog
```

In fact, any `meteor` command I type into the console is followed with the `Update package catalog` message

Here is the list of my packages

- meteor-platform
- insecure
- less
- nemo64:bootstrap
- accounts-ui
- accounts-password
- fourseven:scss
- accounts-ui-unstyled
- jquery
- cfs:standard-packages
- cfs:gridfs
- meteorhacks:npm
- npm-container
- cfs:filesystem

I created a new meteor project in the EC2 instance and that one launches just fine, no problems. I don't know what specific part of my other project is causing this problem.

When running meteor locally (OSX), I do not encounter any of these problems.

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Great idea on creating another project on the same box - I think the second app on the same instance verifies there aren't any EC2 security rules preventing outbound connections. Can you verify on the instance there is a .meteor directory and more specifically the contents of the release file?

Comment: I tried to add the `meteorhacks:npm` library to the 2nd app (one that seemed to be working), but that one is also having issues.
` => Errors while adding packages:             

                                              
While downloading meteorhacks:async@1.0.0...:
error: connect ETIMEDOUT


While downloading meteorhacks:npm@1.2.2...:
error: connect ETIMEDOUT`


Release says "METEOR@1.0.4.2"

It may be an EC2 sec rule as you suggested since I cannot `git clone` either. It's weird because I haven't changed any security rules.
Apologies on the formatting, not sure how to newline in comments

Answer (score 0):

Please check your EC2 instance as meteor packages are downloading from [Meteor Packages](https://packages.meteor.com/) which is hosted on **https**, So add 443 in inbound or in outbound as per your requirement which will help you to fix above issue.